# Getting value from selected multiple checkbox

Tags: php

I have a form to selecting some items using GET method like:

```
<form action="room_selected.php" method="get" id="formget" name="formget">
<input type="checkbox" id="room_id[]" name="room_id[]" value="1">
<input type="text" id="room_price[]" name="room_price[]" value="150000">

<input type="checkbox" id="room_id[]" name="room_id[]" value="2">
<input type="text" id="room_price[]" name="room_price[]" value="250000">

<input type="checkbox" id="room_id[]" name="room_id[]" value="3">
<input type="text" id="room_price[]" name="room_price[]" value="350000">
```

If I select `checkbox` contain value 1 and value 3, in `room_selected.php` only appear `room` 1 and `room` 3 including `price`150000 and `price` 350000.

I try using `for` but not working, like :

```
<?php
for ($i=0;$i<count($_GET['room_idi']);$i++) {
echo $_GET['room_idi'][$i].$_GET['room_price'][$i];
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean `$_GET['room_id']` and not `$_GET['room_idi']`?

Comment: The problem with this is, `$_GET` is an array, but for example, `$_GET['passed']` is a string, not an array and therefore cannot be used as one. The way to do this would be to use `$_POST` instead, then this can be used as an array within an array

Comment: @Albzi yup, I mean is $_GET['room_id'] not $_GET['room_idi']. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here looks to be that because you are only selecting two checkboxes, your for loop will loop only twice. So the PHP page will see two checkbox values, and three text field values;

You could try something like this instead;

```
<form action="room_selected.php" method="get" id="formget" name="formget">
<input type="checkbox" id="room_id[]" name="room_id[]" value="1">
<input type="text" id="room_price[]" name="room_price_1" value="150000">

<input type="checkbox" id="room_id[]" name="room_id[]" value="2">
<input type="text" id="room_price[]" name="room_price_2" value="250000">

<input type="checkbox" id="room_id[]" name="room_id[]" value="3">
<input type="text" id="room_price[]" name="room_price_2" value="350000">

<?php

if (count($_GET['room_id']) > 0) {
    foreach ($_GET['room_id'] as $roomId) {
        $textFieldName = "room_price_" + $roomId;

        echo $roomId . ' = ' . $_GET[$textFieldName];
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank's it works but $textFieldName = "room_price_" + $roomId; shall be $textFieldName = "room_price_".$roomId; Thank's all

Comment: Yes, sorry about the error. The joys of switching between Java and PHP